# `~Q` do not work in my filter?

Tags: python, django

I want to query the `status != 4`:

```
from django.db.models import Q
...
queryset = User.objects.filter(is_staff=True, is_admin=True, ~Q(status = 4), )
```

But I gets wrong:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

How to do with that?  seems the `~Q` do not work?

Comment: `~Q(status == 4)` or `Q(status != 4)`?

Comment: What does "do not work" mean? errors? invalid results? what *does* happen? Have you overridden user? Django's user model doesn't have a status field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
queryset = User.objects.filter(is_staff=True, is_admin=True).exclude(status=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, you cannot have positional arguments after keyword arguments. You have to use `Q` as the first argument to `filter`.

```
queryset = User.objects.filter(~Q(status = 4), is_staff=True, is_admin=True)
```